# External Method call help

Tags: java

So what im trying to do is to call an external method upon an object, its a bit trickier than I expected and am having problems properly implementing it.
The method is:

attack(Player victim)

The method needs to call a hit() method on an object; then if the hit() method was successful (test this through a boolean?):

- use an if statement to call a damage() method upon the object to determine the damage
- call takeDamage() upon (PlayerVictim) to inflict the damage.

Here's the player class that ive coded so far; the attack() method is at the bottom.
**My main question is how to use an external method(s) damage() on the currentWeapon  and takeDamage() on Player Victim**

```
public class Player
{
   private String myPlayerName;
   private Weapon myWeapon;
   private int myCurrentHealth;
   private int myMaxHealth;
   private int myNumPotions;


    /**
     * Constructor initializing class Player
     * Parameters of the player should be:
     * player name, players initial health, the players weapon.
     */
    public Player(String myPlayer, int initialHealth, Weapon currentWeapon) {
        myPlayerName = myPlayer;
        this.myWeapon = currentWeapon;
        myMaxHealth = 30; 
        myCurrentHealth = initialHealth;
        myNumPotions = 0;       
    }

    /**
     * Attack method which attacks opposing player
     * with current equipped weapon.
     */
    public void attack(Player victim) {
        currentWeapon.hit();
        if (boolean currentWeapon.hit() = true) {
            currentWeapon.damage(int dam);
            return dam;

        }
        Player victim.takeDamage(int damage);

    }


}
```

and the weapon class:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Weapon
{
    private int myHitProb;
    private int myMaxDamage;
    private Random myRNG;

    /**
     * Create a new weapon with a hit probability and damage
     */
    public Weapon(int hitProb, int damage) {
        myHitProb = hitProb;
        myMaxDamage = damage;
        myRNG = new Random();
    }

    public boolean hit() {

        int r = myRNG.nextInt(100);

        if (r < myHitProb) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int damage() {
        int dam = myRNG.nextInt(myMaxDamage) + 1;        
        return dam;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the attack() method is wrong.. Im not exactly sure how to call the damage() method on the currentWeapon object to return the damage that was done..

Comment: Your code looks like a method signature or pseudo-code. If this is homework, you should try to do something, then if you get an error and can't figure out, ask a specific question regarding that error, but don't expect people to do your homework for you. And even if they did, you wouldn't be helping yourself in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Your `attack()` method may be many things, but compilable java it is not.
Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
public void attack(Player victim) {
    if (currentWeapon.hit()) {
        victim.takeDamage(currentWeapon.damage());
    }
}
```

Try to remember this guideline: If it seems hard, you're probably doing it the wrong way (unless you're working on the [Mars Lander program](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/phoenix/main/index.html) :) )

Comment: Thank you for that.
I am going to sit back, and re look at my code, and try to see what doesnt isnt working the way it is intended, and why.